# Glossaries won't display in "documentclass" book

Tags: glossaries, books

So, I've noticed this is kind of a recurring problem here and even though I searched and tried so many things, my glossaries simply won't pop up on my pdf.

Now, I just want to say that I'm fairly new to LaTeX and am currently using Overleaf as my terminal.

You guys may notice that I study at KTH in Stockholm, Sweden and that we use our own kth-mag.cls which is huge and I never took the time to actually go through it, if you need information about what's on there, please tell!

Last I'm pretty sure it is documentclass book because they use "mainmatter".

Any help is golden!

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{kth-mag}
    \usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}
    %\glsdisablehyper
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage[table]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
    \usepackage{todonotes}
    \usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{amsthm}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[swedish,english]{babel}
    \usepackage{modifications}
    \usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{textcomp}
    \usepackage{listings}
    \usepackage{color}
    \usepackage{amssymb}
    \usepackage{dirtree}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{longtable}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \usepackage{csquotes}
    \usepackage{graphicx}

    \addbibresource{references.bib}

    \extrafloats{1000}

    % ---------- Abbreviations ----------
    \newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
    \newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
    \newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
    % -----------------------------------

    % ---------- Nomenclature ----------
    \newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
      name = $a$ ,
      description = The number of angels per unit area,
    }
    \newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
      name = $N$ ,
      description = The number of angels per needle point
    }
    \newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
      name = $A$ ,
      description = The area of the needle point
    }
    % ----------------------------------

    \makeglossaries

    \title{Title goes here}

    \subtitle{Subtitle goes here}
    \foreigntitle{Title in Swedish goes here}

    \author{Student1\\Student2}
    \date{\today}
    \blurb{Bachelor's Thesis at ITM\\Supervisor: Supervisor goes here \\ Examiner: Examiner goes here}
    \trita{TRITA xxx yyyy-nn}

    \begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \pagestyle{empty}
    \removepagenumbers
    \maketitle
    \selectlanguage{english}


    \clearpage
    \begin{abstract}

    Write the abstract here.

    \end{abstract}
    \clearpage
    \begin{foreignabstract}{swedish}

    Abstract in Swedish goes here.

    \end{foreignabstract}
    \clearpage

    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}

    I would like to thank...

    \clearpage
    \tableofcontents*
    \clearpage
    \listoffigures*
    \clearpage
    \listoftables*

    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]

    \printglossary[title=Nomenclature]

    \mainmatter
    \pagestyle{newchap}

    \chapter{Introduction}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Converting your code to an MWE and doing `pdflatex > makeglossaries > pdflatex > pdflatex` you will get the glossaries in you pdf.

Note the added `\glsaddall`   to list all entries.

[image: a]

[image: b]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex 

\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[acronym]{glossaries}

% ---------- Abbreviations ----------
\newacronym{ny}{NY}{New York}
\newacronym{la}{LA}{Los Angeles}
\newacronym{un}{UN}{United Nations}
% -----------------------------------

% ---------- Nomenclature ----------
\newglossaryentry{angelsperarea}{
name = $a$ ,
description = The number of angels per unit area,
}
\newglossaryentry{numofangels}{
name = $N$ ,
description = The number of angels per needle point
}
\newglossaryentry{areaofneedle}{
name = $A$ ,
description = The area of the needle point
}
% ----------------------------------

\makeglossaries

\title{Title goes here} 

\glsaddall %  to list all entries <<<<<

\begin{document}
    \frontmatter
    \pagestyle{empty}
    
    \chapter*{Acknowledgements}
    
    I would like to thank...
    
    \printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=Abbreviations]
    
    \printglossary[title=Nomenclature]
    
    \mainmatter
    
    \chapter{Introduction}

\end{document}
```